# I need to programatically get and set ACL's (access control list) for an Ubuntu 14.04 desktop computer using the ext4 filesytem

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu-14.04, dacl

I need to programatically get and set ACL's  (access control list) for an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop computer using the ext4 filesytem. I was wondering if there is C or C++ library function to this. I need this C/C++ function to initialize a supplied security descriptor with a DACL that grants the Authenticated Users group GENERIC_READ, GENERIC_WRITE and GENERIC_EXECUTE access. I googled this topic since this afternoon yesterday and found only information on the getacl and setacl Linux command line utilities. Do I have to write custom C or C++ functions and data structures to accomplish this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu's implementation of ACL's for ext4 are based on the [POSIX.1e](http://wt.tuxomania.net/publications/posix.1e/download.html) standard (a withdrawn standard but still used by many Unix and Linux variations) and you can use the `acl_` POSIX functions to achieve what you want. For Ubuntu, you can view the [manpage for the `acl` entries](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/acl.5.html) to see which functions are supported (and their subsequent documentation).

Hope that can help.